# Undefined while console.log()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

**Codes in app.js**

```
app.post('/compose', function(req, res){
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };
  console.log(post);
  res.redirect('/compose');

});
```

**Codes in ejs file**

```
<%- include('partials/header') -%>

<h1>Compose</h1>

<form action="/compose" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">

    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control name="postTitle">
    <label>Post</label>
    <textarea class="form-control name="postBody" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>

  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Publish</button 

</form> 
<%- include('partials/footer') -%>
```

Output: [Output is undefine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whOhq.png)

Comment: `console.log(req.body)` will probably help you figure out the issue

Comment: what is the content of ```req.body``` ? are you sure to have parsed the body (in your  form that'd be to parse body when ```content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` that is ```app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: yourchoice}))```

Comment: Yeah I have done that ... but it still not parsing the contents

Comment: Do you have appropriate middleware running before your request handler to parse the body to populate `req.body`?  If not, see this answer [No request info in POST from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583577/no-request-from-form-in-node-js/59584004#59584004).

Comment: There is  quotes left unclosed of both input class <input type="text"  class="form-control name="postTitle">

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I got it Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty body in req is always because of lack of `bodyparser`.

Please add `app.use(express.urlencoded());` after app declaration to enable parsing of your body.

PS: You cannot give an HTML button type of submit. You either use an input type submit or a simple button at the end of the form to trigger submits.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Publish</button>
```

**Rather then this, please try to use below Code**

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"/>
```